# He was angry with his brother. VS. He was angry at his brother

Tags: prepositions

> He was angry **with** his brother.

> He was angry **at** his brother.

Any different usage could be? Or exactly the same?

Comment: The first is usual. You are more likely to be angry _at_ a set of circumstances than a person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule is that you're angry **with** people and **at** objects or situations. In practice, *angry at* can be used with people as well (though it seems to be [more of an AmE thing](https://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/topic/angry-at-with-about#:%7E:text=In%20British%20English%2Cone%20is,with%20and%20angry%20at%20someone.)), but *angry with* is pretty much exclusive to people, and has a personifying connotation when used with objects.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Interestingly, **angry with** is much more common.

To my ear, there is a difference when you refer to a person.

> I am angry at Tom.            (a bit more anger; more pointed)
>
> I am angry with Tom.